# Xampp not starting on mac by simple pressing start

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have installed xaamp on mac min..if i start it from clicking start in manage-os x its not starting apache or mysql server..

but if writing this code in terminal

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apachectl start
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql.server start
```

I tried by changing ports of config file but didn't work.

Comment: just reinstall.

Comment: I don't think that's the solution because it happened to another mac mini too.